# Controller failing to bind property

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

My controller is failing to bind properties on form submission.

Here's the controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterInputModel inputModel)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"email: {inputModel.Email}");
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Here's the form:

```html
<form method="post" asp-route="RegisterUser">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.Email" class="form-control" autofocus />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

```cs
public class RegisterInputModel
{
    Required]
    EmailAddress]
    Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    Required]
    StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters 
    long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
            
    DataType(DataType.Password)]
    Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

After debugging the submitted data does come through the `Request` property of the controller but the binding fails.

Comment: Hi @Chris Claude, what is your Request property? And if you use `asp-route="RegisterUser"`, it even cannot get into the RegisterUser action in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you use asp.net core mvc, you need change `asp-route="RegisterUser"` to `asp-action="RegisterUser"`.

Secondly, model binding system looks through the source by name and `asp-for` will generate the id and name in html. So you can see that your name here is something like:`RegisterInput.PropertyName`, it does not match the backend property name. You need add `[Bind(Prefix = "RegisterInput")]` to specific the prefix of the name or you can change the `RegisterInputModel inputModel` to `RegisterInputModel RegisterInput`.

Here is the whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public RegisterInputModel RegisterInput { get; set; }
}
public class RegisterInputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

View(**Index.cshtml**):

```
@model YourModel

<form method="post" asp-action="RegisterUser">  //change here...
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.Email" class="form-control" autofocus />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterInput.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    //render Index.cshtml view...
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult RegisterUser([Bind(Prefix = "RegisterInput")]
                                                 RegisterInputModel inputModel)
    //public IActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterInputModel RegisterInput)
    {
        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    //...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //....
        services.AddControllersWithViews()                    
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing this `[Bind(Prefix = "RegisterInput")]`. I renamed RegisterInput class to RegisterInputModel at some point and forgot to rename the variable (RegisterInput in the HTML) as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to add AntiForgeryToken just below a form tag, or remove it from a controller action

```
<form method="post" asp-route="RegisterUser">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net Core Controller/View (not Razor page), I usually use the below approach,

1. A Get method to view the page with an empty model
2. Prepare the form using the model
3. Submit the form

You can check the below code as a reference

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult RegisterUser()
{
    var model = new RegisterInputModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterInputModel inputModel)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"email: {inputModel.Email}");
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

**View:**

```
@model RegisterInput

<form method="post">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" autofocus />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```